# set magento 2.4.3 website root directory ubuntu

Tags: magento2.4.3, pub

I have upgraded `Magento v2.3.3-p1` to `Magento v2.4.3` successfully. When I ran the website it's showing **404 Notfound** error, due to not set the `Document Root`. When I ran the website **http://localhost/mce243/pub/** it's showing, but not redirecting other than home page.

And I have updated the `/etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf` file with the below code in ubuntu for `Document Root` directory, but not working for me.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

         ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
         DocumentRoot /var/www/html/
         ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
         CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
         <Directory "/var/www/html">
                     AllowOverride all
         </Directory>
 </VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost http://10.10.10.120/mce243/:8080>

    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/mce243/pub
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

And also updated .htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/pub/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/setup/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/update/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/dev/
RewriteRule .* /pub/$0 [L]
DirectoryIndex pub/index.php
```

both are not working.

In my system having **multiple Magento instances**.

Can you please help me how to run the **specific website with pub index.php as root**?

Answer (score 0):

*First Edit .htaccess file and paste this code I just Remove **/** in*

```
RewriteRule .* pub/$0 [L]
```

**.htaccess**

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/pub/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/setup/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/update/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/dev/
RewriteRule .* pub/$0 [L]
DirectoryIndex index.php
```

*Next in DB `core_config_data`*

```
web/seo/use_rewrites set  0
```

*and last give full permission Magento*

```
sudo chmod 777 -R /var/www/html/mce243
```

After That Run /Index.php in  url

```
http://localhost/mce243/index.php
```

Comment: let me try this.

Comment: After that run below /index.php url  =>  
http://localhost/mce243/index.php

Comment: showing website i.e., all(header, footer, menu) are showing, but the body showing **404 Not Found** error. **Whoops, our bad..**

Comment: Please share screenshot

Comment: https://tinyurl.com/yzwutnqk

Comment: try /index.php in url

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/130511/discussion-between-bojjaiah-and-savan-patel).

Comment: if we add `index.php` it's working, but in the real time `index.php` is require. How can we run without adding `index.php`? Please suggest.

Comment: @Bojjaiah Brother for run without adding index.php we have to do R & D for this. it's take a time.

Comment: Yes, I tried several ways. But not worked for me. If you find any Please share the references/resources.